# Could not add reference for Entity Framework 6 after download from NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, entity-framework-6

In **visual studio 2010** i have downloaded **NuGet** and install **Entity Framework 6**. But by manually i delete the reference file from **references**. After that i want to add again that reference file. Can any one give me steps to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve that situation

- Right click on references and click add reference
- Browse for dll
- Navigate to the packages directory for that solution (where all your downloaded nuget packages and stored)
- Manually add the reference for EF6
- This should bring you back to the point prior to when you manually deleted your package reference

or

- Open the packages.config file and delete the EF6 package reference
- Open your csproj file and find the reference to EF6 package in there and delete it (This was likely already removed as a result of your manual reference delete)
- This should remove all mention of that package from your project so go ahead and install it again